# Visual Studio Add Service Reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, soap

Does anyone have anything against using this vs. creating your own proxy classes?

Also, does anyone have a good overview of using Web Service Reference?  I searched the net but couldn't find any good articles.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same thing. It has pretty much the same options as svcutil.exe does.

Comment: Just wondering about the quality of the classes created.  I created my own one time until my boss said hey, next time you can just auto generate all this in VS

Comment: "The quality of the classes". Rephrase that. "Just wondering whether Microsoft, for the past several years, has been producing low-quality proxy classes, in source code form, for everyone to make fun of." Than answer the rephrased question.

Comment: What are you smoking today John?  :)

Comment: I quit 15 years ago. What are you referring to? I often find such "inverse" arguments useful. When I used to smoke, I'd sometimes search frantically for cigarettes. I learned a trick to find them: cigarette packs can only be hiding where there's room for them to hide. So, under the bed, maybe. Under that sheet of paper, no. Where could Microsoft have hidden poor quality classes, such that you would not have heard about it? Nowhere.